# Popover not showing after dom element changed

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the [Bootstrap 3](http://www.getbootstrap.com) frame work to create an table with some popovers in my `<td>`. I only show the popover, if the icon (`<i>`) for the popover is clicked, else I perform another function, once the td is clicked. However, if the td is changed, the popover stops working and I can't seem to figure out why. I've created an jsFiddle, which displays the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/pNxa8/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pNxa8/10/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setPopo();
});

function changeColor(row)
{

    $(row).find('td i.nextPopover').popover('hide');
    inner = row.innerHTML;
    if(row.style.backgroundColor == 'white')
       { 
          row.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          var tmp = inner.replace('</td>'," <i style='display:inline-block;margin-left:-25px;' class='fa fa-check pull-right'></i></td>");
          row.innerHTML = tmp;
          setPopo();
       }
    else
    {

        row.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        var tmp = inner.replace('<i style="display:inline-block;margin-left:-25px;" class="fa fa-check pull-right"></i></td>',"</td>");
       row.innerHTML = tmp;

       setPopo();
    }
}


function setPopo()
{
    $('tr').each( function() { 
        $(this).find('.nextPopover').popover('hide');
        $(this).unbind('click');});
    $('tr').each(  function() {  $(this).on('click', function() { 

        changeColor(this )      }) }  );
   $('.nextPopover').popover('destroy');
    $('.nextPopover').popover();
    $('.nextPopover').click(function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).popover();
        $('.nextPopover').not(this).popover('hide');
    });    
}
```

Comment: This worked great as initializer, but it doesn't work once i've clicked a tr, even though I did call setPopo() after the click. Does it matter, that the dom element was created by PHP?

Comment: Please, can you take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5oifnV7G6o , it's my desktop record with chromium browser, i was thinking that every thing was ok...

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying that you jsFiddle isn't working, but for my actual problem (which the fiddle tried to mimic), my elements are created by PHP.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you question?

Comment: Excuse me I delete my last (stupid) comment. I don't think it's because it's generate by php... Which navigator do you use ?

Comment: Navigator? I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: IE 8 ? Firefox ? Chrome ?

Comment: Tried on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It works on Firefox, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the click event, you bind it to a DOM element. If you change this DOM element the new one isn't binded.

You could bind the new element, or use the `delegate` function (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)